# Powerbuilder 11.5 - Cannot install Database Interfaces

Tags: installation, powerbuilder

I uninstalled and tried to re-install PB 11.5.1. I am using Windows 10 and before the uninstall the PB was working OK (I have installed it on Windows 8.1 and then updated to Windows 10 but it was working OK).

The installation of the PB was fine but when I launch PB, I get an error:

```
No Database interfaces are installed.
```

I try but I cannot get the Database Interfaces to install.

I get an error :

```
Note:PkgMgr has been deprecated. Please update your scripts to use DISM.exe to install.
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have reached a dead end and that you have no other option than to install a supported OS (or perhaps use a VM with a supported OS). You were lucky that it continued to work correctly after the windows 10 upgrade. And - of course - that version of PB is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

No luck. Fortunately my Windows Previous Version option worked!